# Is there any third party api in java to get cities based on country

Tags: java

Earlier I've used maxmind geoip to get country based on ip.

Now I need to list out all states & cities based on the given country value. Any one aware of any Api to achieve this?

Comment: better search for such web service or JSON or XML or any other format and parse that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any API, but you can use the following link to download the dumps of all cities country wise.

http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Finding the city or country would be easier as this service is provided by Google, Yahoo and Geonames. For populating all the cities i would suggest you to download the dumps from the link and store it in and DB of yours and create your own private(or public if you feel so) web service. This way it would be much easier.